# How to add one more file name in url before index.php dynamically set from front end in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

1.Initial URL  `ProjectName/English/index.php/controller1/function1`

on request from front end

1. `ProjectName/French/index.php/controller2/function2`
2. `ProjectName/German/index.php/controller3/function3`
3. `ProjectName/Deutch/index.php/controller4/functioI4`

i get the `htaccess` code to remove index.php but unable to get the code to execute above requirement.

Whole Controllers are in one codeigniter application.

Comment: Why you can't redirect to corresponding URLs while switching language from front end.

Comment: In redirection Path is changed so functions will not get executed as all Controller is in one codeigniter set.

Comment: This is a bad practice. If you want to change the language you should handle it with a separate function. And sending language in URL like this `ProjectName/French/`, `ProjectName/German/` won't be helpful and you shouldn't do this.

Comment: There are multiple controllers and functions under same project.

Comment: take a look here and take your time to understand such concepts ... https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/i18n-Multi-language-Library-Helper

Answer (score 0):

Use Routes as follows in routes.php 
your url call will be for french : ProjectName/French/controller2/function2 will call function2 of controller2

```
$route['French/controller2/function2'] = 'controller2/function2';
$route['German/controller3/function3'] = 'controller3/function3';
$route['Deutch/controller4/function4'] = 'controller4/function4';
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to remove index.php from url in your .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
order deny,allow
#deny from all
allow from all
#allow from 116.193.161.42 103.212.0.0/16 61.95.235.67

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```